# How do I replace a key with a variable when extracting data from a hash array?

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I'm trying to use a user generated variable as a key when retrieving info from a 2d hash array:

```
warehouse["warehouse_b"][:a6]
```

Why does this code work:

```
location = :a6
warehouse["warehouse_a"][location]
```

while this code doesn't?

```
location = gets.chomp # User inputs :a6
warehouse["warehouse_a"][location]
```

Comment: What is a 2d hash array?

Comment: How is `warehouse["warehouse_b"][:a6]` relevant to your question? Does it have any relation with `warehouse` or even `warehouse["warehouse_a"][:a6]`?

Answer (score 3):

With `gets`method you get a string. In your case location has to be a symbol. You can do

```
puts warehouse[hash][location.to_sym]
```

or

```
location = gets.chomp.to_sym
```

Comment: Brilliant. Exactly what I was after. Thank you. Much obliged.